# Is my prayer invalid?

Tags: salat

When I was praying when I was doing rukoo I was about to fall and and hold the bed beside me and completed my rukoo. I just want a yes or no answer if my prayer is valid or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You were about to fall, and you instinctively grabbed something nearby to keep your stance.

Comment: Thanks but I did my prayer again to remove my anxiety.